# Problems with my new linux gaming setup

Tags: drivers, graphics, games, steam

I just started using Ubuntu 21.04 because I always wanted to use Linux instead of Windows and the main drawback for me years ago was in the gaming aspect, but after doing some quick research I discovered that at this point of time, most of the games I play are playable on Linux, that got me very excited and decided to install Ubuntu.

Regardless, I haven't been able to play anything besides Vallheim, I already installed the GPU drivers and some other basic stuff, but I don't know how to troubleshoot properly on this OS yet, and I am also getting some stuttering issues that I never encountered before with this pc I have built.

This is What I've Done:

- Installed Ubuntu
- Installed Steam
- Installed Lutris
- Downloaded the nvidia driver metapackage 465 and installed
- Activated the proton option on steam
- Downloaded the games, Vallheim,Vampyr, Warhammer 40k Mechanicus, Warhammer 40k Dawn of war

None of those games with the exception of Vallheim were able to open, the apps and the funcionality of the rest of the OS appear to be normal besides an Issue with my PCI wifi card which appears 2 times on the upper bar and a bit of Stuttering when using multiple apps at the same time.

My specs are as follows:

- Intel i5 8th gen
- Nvidia 1660 oc 6GB
- 32 gb ram at 2666 Mhz
- 500 ssd for system
- 4tb hdd for games

I would be very thankful if someone could assist me.

Comment: Please edit your question and add details about a specific issue you are encountering. Perhaps a particular game you can't play. Give all appropriate error messages.  Vague problem descriptions are unlikely to get helped.

Comment: Thank you for your response, the thing is that I am not getting any error that I could see, I just clicked play and when the games are supposed to run they don't but no crash reports, or anything. The games I've tried were Vampyr, Warhammer 40k dawn of war, and WHM 40k mechanicus

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I have edited the document and provided as much information as I am available to gather, I appreciate your attention.

Comment: Steam tags the games that play on Linux with "Steam" icon,  games that play on Windows have a "Windows" icon.  Check the OS requirements for your games, e.g. Vaympr only has a Windows icon and do not expect it to play on Linux.

Comment: @ubfan1 There is a compatibility layer based on Wine called Proton on Steam nowadays which allows running many Windows-only games on Linux. Anyway, those that are released on Linux should run at least. In that case, trying to start the game from the command line may give some hints. Find the executable with Right-click on the game -> Properties -> Local Files -> Browse. Start the executable from there in a terminal and post the output.